# Getting the Application Black screen and the Main activity also get restarted on configuration changes

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, qml

I have added all the possible configuration changes in the AndroidManifest.xml still My main activity getting restarted, following are the possible configuration changes added in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|mnc|mcc|
                touchscreen|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|
                navigation|colorMode" android:name="org.myapp.qt.MyAppActivity" 
                android:label="MyApp ABC&amp; XYZ" android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
                android:launchMode="singleTop" 
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
```

Comment: Well, did you also override `onConfigurationChanged` in `MyAppActivity`?

Comment: Yes I have override onConfigurationChanged

Comment: @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  
  Resources res = s_activity.getResources();
  Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
   
  Log.d("Configuration Changed", conf.toString()); }
 this is the onConfigurationChmged method which i have overided in my code